# Looking for a book (or series) in which people who had a magic word became magical

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

in this book one word would make people magical and if you had more than one word you became more powerful. There was a limitation in that if more than one person knew the word it was rendered less effective. I remember reading the first book in what seemed to be a series but lost track and now that is all i remember.

Comment: probable duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14836/magic-is-based-on-words-of-power-which-series (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 6):

Dave Duncan, the "A Man of His Word" series.
Main characters: Rap, Inos.
http://daveduncan.com/books/books.php

This [GoodReads review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/23204993?book_show_action=true) of the first book explains the premise of how the words work, matching the questioner's details:

> the source of all magic appears to be these words of power. If you know one then you're super-human in some way [...] A second word makes you great at all human endeavors, and super-human feats like forsight and such tend to go with a second word. A third makes you a sorcerer with arcane powers. [...]  However, each person who knows a Word shares the power of the Word - so the more people who know the Word the less power you have