# Man becomes flag-bearer to the King and falls in love with King's wife

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read a novel in 2003-2004 which is written in English and had multiple story lines in it. One was about a man that became the flag bearer to the king and and falls in love with the king's wife. Another part of the story is about a mage married to the queen that was once one of the most powerful mages in the realm but he shared his words of power with a crowd of people so his power was diminished.

If anyone has read this book or knows the name it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you tell us when you read this book, in what language, how old it seems to be, and whether it is a novel?  If so, please edit the question to add the new information.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sentinel_(2006_film)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lancelot

Answer (score 4):

I suspect the book you are thinking of is one of the series [A Handful of Men](https://www.goodreads.com/series/40824-a-handful-of-men) by Dave Duncan.

This series is a sequel to [A Man of His Word](https://www.goodreads.com/series/53081-a-man-of-his-word) which follows the adventures of stableboy Rap and princess Inosolan.  By the end of that series

> Rap has become the most powerful sorcerer in the land by mastering 5 words of magic.  He share 4 of the words with Inosolan and she shared those words with a crowd of people - making Rap an almost ordinary man again

A Handful of Men picks up a few years later and adds some new characters.  One of those is Ylo - an imperial soldier who falls in love with the wife of his imperor (king).

Comment: is a dwarf trapped in a magic bubble?

Comment: It is a while since I read them so I am not really sure. Having said that there are definitely dwarves in the story and being trapped in a magic bubble sounds familiar

Comment: Just checked my copy and yes the villain (a dwarf called Zinixo) was trapped in a magic bubble by Rap - "I wrapped him up in an unbreakable soap bubble that stopped magic. He still had his power then, but he couldn't
use it."

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14836/magic-is-based-on-words-of-power-which-series (question about previous series)